# How to put multiple Custom Popups in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'd like to create a Multiple Custom Popups in Google Maps.
The docmentation just put one popup, but I need a map with many popups, in different places.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup#maps_overlay_popup-html